# Проверка данных с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, которое будет проверять данные на соответствие следующей структуре:
**текст,(запятая),цифры**

Пример: **Москва,101100**

```
if (...) {
   die('success');
} else {
   die('error');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код писал "на коленке", может понадобится корректировка:

```
$str = 'Москва,101100';
$patt = '~\pL+,\d+~u';

if (preg_match($patt, $str)) {
    die('success');
} else {
    die('error');
}
```